# Get parents from a table and count there childs in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

How to select all the parents from a table and count how many child they have

**Here is my code:**

```
DB::table('wiki_page')
    ->where('wiki_page.parent_id', '=', null)
    ->get();
```

**Table**

```
 id  |   name  | parent_id
 -------------------------
 1   | Laravel |  null
 2   | PHP     |   1
 3   | Dingo   |   1
 4   | Lumen   |  null
 5   | Semver  |   4
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the schema of the table? @ZeeshanAhmed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to do like :

```
DB::table('wiki_page')->selectRaw('wiki_page.*, COUNT(wp.id) AS child')
    ->join('wiki_page AS wp','wiki_page.id','=','wp.parent_id')
    ->where('wiki_page.parent_id', '=', null)
    ->groupBy('wiki_page.id')
    ->get();
```